Unable to recognize Spring Boot JPA interface
When trying to create a custom JPA interface for Spring Boot in the same directory and package, the build fails due to the alphabetical order of the spelling.

PlayerRepository comes before PlayerRepositoryCustom in alphabetical order. Therefore, the build fails.
PlayerRepository comes after OlayerRepositoryCustom in alphabetical order. Therefore, the build succeeds.

Build Failed
I defined the PlayerRepository and PlayerRepositoryCustom interfaces in the same package and directory.
And I set up PlayerRepository to extend PlayerRepositoryCustom (for a custom SpringBoot JPA interface).
However, due to a "cannot find symbol PlayerRepositoryCustom" error, it fails to recognize the PlayerRepositoryCustom interface.
src/main/java/com/test/springtest/repository/PlayerRepository.java
package com.test.springtest.repository;
// ... import omit ...
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, MemberPK>, PlayerRepositoryCustom
{
    @NonNull List<Player> findAll();
}

src/main/java/com/test/springtest/repository/PlayerRepositoryCustom.java
package com.test.springtest.repository;
// ... import omit ...
public interface PlayerRepositoryCustom
{
    List<Player> findsOffset(int limit, int offset);
}

src/main/java/com/test/springtest/repository/PlayerRepositoryCustomImpl.java
package com.test.springtest.repository;
// ... import omit ...
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlayerRepositoryCustomImpl implements PlayerRepositoryCustom {
    private final EntityManager em;
    @Override
    public List<Player> findsOffset(int limit, int offset) {
        // ... omit ...
    }
}

And Result
$ ./gradlew build
Custom actions are attached to task ':compileJava'.
Caching disabled for task ':compileJava' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
  Input property 'stableSources' file ..../src/main/java/com/test/springtest/repository/PklayerRepositoryCustom.java has been removed.
  Input property 'stableSources' file ..../src/main/java/com/test/springtest/repository/PklayerRepositoryCustomImpl.java has been removed.
  Input property 'stableSources' file ..../src/main/java/com/test/springtest/repository/PlayerRepository.java has changed.
  and more...
Compilation mode: in-process compilation
Created classpath snapshot for incremental compilation in 0.005 secs.
Compiling with toolchain '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.12/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home'.
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
..../src/main/java/com/test/springtest/repository/PlayerRepository.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, MemberPK>, PlayerRepositoryCustom
                                                                           ^
  symbol: class PlayerRepositoryCustom
1 error
Incremental compilation of 9 classes completed in 0.156 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I have tried various methods, such as removing Gradle's cache, but the interface is still not being recognized, resulting in the error mentioned above.
Build Success
The build was successful when I either put all the unrecognized interfaces into a single file, or changed 'Player' to 'Olayer' (placing it ahead of 'Player' in alphabetical order).
Build Success Case 1
src/main/java/com/test/springtest/repository/PlayerRepository.java
package com.test.springtest.repository;
// ... import omit ...
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, MemberPK>, PlayerRepositoryCustom
{
    @NonNull List<Player> findAll();
}
interface PlayerRepositoryCustom
{
    List<Player> findsOffset(int limit, int offset);
}
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class PlayerRepositoryCustomImpl implements PlayerRepositoryCustom {
    private final EntityManager em;
    @Override
    public List<Player> findsOffset(int limit, int offset) {
        // ... omit ...
    }
}

Build Success Case 2

Change Interface name PlayerRepositoryCustom to PaaalayerRepositoryCustom or OlayerRepositoryCustom, NlayerRepositoryCustom, MlayerRepositoryCustom ... AlayerRepositoryCustom
Change Class name PlayerRepositoryCustomImpl to PaaalayerRepositoryCustomImpl or OlayerRepositoryCustomImpl, NlayerRepositoryCustomImpl, MlayerRepositoryCustomImpl ... AlayerRepositoryCustomImpl

And Result.
$ ./gradlew build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 574ms
7 actionable tasks: 7 up-to-date

Version

Spring Boot: 3.3.4
Gradle: 8.10.1

I want to know the cause of this error and how to solve it.
Thank you.
